# Cannot read text file into array and write to text file again

Tags: java

This my whole code. 
I want to make a simple program that will read a
text file and put it to array then write it to the
same text file,
also can add and delete the existing input and my input.

**Problem**

The delete and writer part seems not working, only blank text file when I run the code

These are the error after I select the exit.

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException at ContactList.writer(ContactList.java:51) at 
ContactListDriver.main(ContactListDriver.java:73) at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at 
edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:27‌​2)






public class Contact {

    //Each contact stores the name, phone number, and email address
    private String name;
    private String number;
    private String email;
    public Contact(String name, String number, String email)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
        this.email = email;
    }   
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public String getNumber()
    {
        return number;
    }

    public String getEmail()
    {
        return email;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number)
    {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email)
    {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

class for processing the inputs.

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.lang.*;
 import java.util.*;


public class ContactList {

    public Contact[] myContacts;
    public static final int MAX = 100;
    private int numContacts;

    public ContactList()
    {
        myContacts = new Contact[MAX];
        numContacts = 0;
    }

    public void addContact(String name, String number, String email)
    {
        Contact c = new Contact(name, number, email);
        myContacts[numContacts] = c;
        numContacts++;
    }

    public void deleteContact(String name)
    {
      for ( int i = 0; i <= numContacts-1 ; i++){
        if(  name == myContacts[i].getName())
        {
         myContacts[i] = null;
           break; 
        }
      }
      numContacts--;   
    } 





  public void writer(){

      String x = "MyContacts.txt";
      try {
   PrintWriter outputs = new PrintWriter(x);

       for( int i=0; i < myContacts.length; i++)
         {

          Contact c = myContacts[i];
              if(c!=null){ // check if c is null before writing to file
                 outputs.println(""+c.getName()+" "+c.getNumber()+" "+c.getName());
                 outputs.flush();
            }

      }

          outputs.close();

    }catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();


  } 
  catch(NullPointerException ex){
  }

  }


    public void displayContacts()
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0; i < myContacts.length; i++)
        {
            Contact c = myContacts[i];

            if(null != c){
            System.out.println("Name: " + c.getName());
            System.out.println("Number: " + c.getNumber());
            System.out.println("Email: " + c.getEmail());
            System.out.println("------------------------------------");

             }
        }
    }



}



    /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
```

The Driver....

```
public class ContactListDriver {    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        ContactList cList = new ContactList();
        File in = new File("MyContacts.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(in);
        int option;
        char again = 'n';

        String name = null;
        String number = null;
        String email = null;


        while(sc.hasNext())
        {
            //read one line from text file
            String entry = sc.nextLine();
            //System.out.println(entry);
            String[] con = entry.split("\\s+");
            //System.out.println(con[0] + " " + con[1] + " " + con[2]);
            cList.addContact(con[0], con[1], con[2]);
        }

        Scanner userIn = new Scanner(System.in);


        do{
            displayOptions();     
            option = userIn.nextInt();


            switch(option)
            {
                case 1:


                    System.out.println(" Name > ");
                    name = userIn.next();

                    System.out.println(" Number > ");
                    number = userIn.next();

                    System.out.println(" Email Address > ");
                    email = userIn.next();

                    cList.addContact(name, number, email);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //delete contact
                    System.out.println("Contact Name > ");
                    name = userIn.next(); 
                    cList.deleteContact(name);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //display contact
                    cList.displayContacts();
                    break;
                case 4:
                  cList.writer();
                  System.out.println(" are you sure ? press y ");
                  String x = userIn.next();
                  again = x.charAt(0);

                    break;
            }



        }while( again == 'n' );  



    }

    private static void displayOptions() {
        System.out.println("(1) Add");
        System.out.println("(2) Delete");
        System.out.println("(3) Show Contacts");
        System.out.println("(4) Exit");
    }




}
```

Comment: And the questions are....? Include this part

Comment: @Abdul what's wrong with this do you get some error?? or exceptions?? Lets us know if any

Comment: yes,the delete and writer part seems not working, 
only blank textfile when I run the code
>>>this are the error after I select the exit.
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ContactList.writer(ContactList.java:51)
 at ContactListDriver.main(ContactListDriver.java:73)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)

Comment: You should really consider using an `ArrayList` instead of an array. This will allow you to avoid null indices in your array. Every time you add a contact, just `add(new Contact())` and your arrayList size will be auto-incremented.

Comment: I want it too but my teacher did not allow me.

Comment: if you are not allowed to use ArrayList then try at least to study the source code of ArrayList. It is not so difficult to understand, and you can transfer the algorithm to your class rather straight forward.

Comment: Do you have a link that I could study the source code of API's like ArrayList?

Comment: If you can't use ArrayList, you should make use of [`System.arraycopy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) .Everytime you add a new contact, copy the array to a new one. Under the hood, that's all pretty much what ArrayList does

Comment: [Link to ArrayList source online:](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java)

Comment: Anyone here??
.. on the delete part, I made like this
for ( int i = 0; i <= numContacts - 1 ; i++).
now NO error, but still cannot delete. any clue?

Comment: @AbdulGamoranao edit your question with new code

Comment: @AbdulGamoranao still you have not changed `name == myContacts[i].getName()` and `numContacts--; ` should be inside `if` condition. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem I see is:

You have  a extra `break;` statement inside  `deleteContact(String name)` function

and `String` comparision `name == myContacts[i].getName()` should be `name.equals(myContacts[i].getName())`

```
 public void deleteContact(String name)
        {
          for ( int i = 0; i <= numContacts-1; i++){
            if(  name.equals( myContacts[i].getName()))// string comparison uses equals();
            {
             myContacts[i] = null;
                numContacts--;  // this line should be inside of if condition 
               break; 
            }
            // break; No need of breaking the loop here
          }
        }
```

Another problem is at `writer()` function

```
public void writer(){

      String x = "MyContacts.txt";
      try {
   PrintWriter outputs = new PrintWriter(x);

       for( int i=0; i < myContacts.length; i++)
         {

          Contact c = myContacts[i];
              if(c!=null){ // check if c is null before writing to file
                 outputs.println(""+c.getName()+" "+c.getNumber()+" "+c.getName());
                 outputs.flush();
            }

      }

          outputs.close();

  }catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();


} 
  catch(NullPointerException ex){ // Or just catch the NPE 
  }
```

Comment: I would not recommend the second patch catching a NPE. We should never use exceptions for controlling the program flow, see Blochs Effective Java.

Comment: @MenoHochschild If the programmer knows the reason behind NPE in code then he/she can handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared and initialized the `Contact` array of size MAX. but,it seems to be that you haven't *initialized* the elements though. i.e. c is null in the below code

```
 Contact c = myContacts[i];
                outputs.println(""+c.getName()+" "+c.getNumber()+" "+c.getName());
                outputs.flush();
```

`myContacts[i]` should return a `Contact` instance. As said by **Meno**, there are lot of other problems in your code. You have to always cover all the possible scenarios while writing the code.

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues with your code so not easy to say where to begin.

First: Your `public void deleteContact(String name)`-method is broken. It compares Strings using == instead of equals(). And worse: It creates null pointers mid in your array which will cause problems in your writer()-method.

Second: Why do you use arrays? You should use `java.util.ArrayList` which offers out-of-the-box implementations for adding, getting and deleting contacts.

Third: If you are missing your text file, you might have overlooked it because of missing path so you don't know where to look for this file. So please add a full path to file name.

Fourth: I would also use scanner.hasNextLine() instead of scanner.hasNext() if you then call scanner.nextLine().

Since you said you are not allowed to use ArrayList you should study its source code especially for removing elements. It does not only nullify the array bucket, but also to shift all following elements one index backwards so you don't have any null gap until the index given by element count. And two breaks in deleteContact()-method are really not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Most importantly you need to fix the `ContactList` class. It is inserting new elements into the last index, and deleting at any location using the `name`.

For example, let's say the `ContactList` has three elements in it at 0, 1 and 2 indexes. So `numContacts` is set to 3.

Now `ContactList` has elements as:

`[0]C0, [1]C1, [2]C2, [3]null, ...`

Then if the contact at 0 index is deleted (set to `null`), then `numContacts` is set to 2. 
Now the `ContactList` has elements as:

`[0]null, [1]C1, [2]C2, [3] null, ...`

A new insert will be added to the index 2, and it will override the C2 value.

Simplest solution is to use an `ArrayList` instead of an array.

As others have mentioned there are few more issues to fix, but above is the most important in my opinion.